# Как перенести надпись вертикальной линий вниз

Tags: javascript, canvas, график, chart.js

Есть построенный график на chartjs, и через prototype.draw нарисована вертикальная линия. Как перенести надпись вертикальной линий вниз, если она выходит за область canvas и не отображается?

```
Chart.elements.Line.prototype.draw = function () {
    this._chart.ctx.save();
    this._chart.ctx.strokeStyle = '#808080';

    var points = this._chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data,
        point_x = points[points.length - 1]._model.x,
        point_y = points[points.length - 1]._model.y,
        bottom = this._chart.scales['y-axis-0'].bottom;

    this._chart.ctx.beginPath();
    this._chart.ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    this._chart.ctx.moveTo(point_x, point_y);
    this._chart.ctx.lineTo(point_x, bottom);

    this._chart.ctx.textAlign = 'right';
    this._chart.ctx.fillStyle = '#808080';
    if ($(window).width() < 420) {
        this._chart.ctx.font = '500 14px "Montserrat", sans-serif';
        this._chart.ctx.fillText("Окупність", point_x - 2, bottom - 14);
    } else {
        this._chart.ctx.font = '500 16px "Montserrat", sans-serif';
        this._chart.ctx.fillText("Окупність", point_x - 5, bottom + 24);
    }

    this._chart.ctx.stroke();
    this._chart.ctx.restore();
}
```

[как сейчас](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AXwX.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[как нужно](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgmQ9.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавьте поясняющий набросок

Comment: @StrangerintheQ есть график который создается при инициализации страницы, на нём есть 2 части графика, одна для отображения окупности, а вторая уже отображение заработка. И вот на последней точке окупности рисуется линия, по x оси в 0 и по y в точке где находиться точка графика. К этой линий  нужно добавить подпись которая будет выводится под графиком, и при изменении параметров двигаться за линией. Сейчас она двигается и перестраивает нормально график, но если ей отобразить внизу графика, то она выходит за границей canvas и не отображается. Как сделать так что он отображалась внизу.

Comment: @вместо тысячи слов прикрепите картинку как есть и как надо

Comment: @StrangerintheQ добавил